# swift 3 removing bulk of text from textFiled

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working for mobile application will send pdf for selected contact, so the user will found add contact button to open table view that have all contact list. after that the user will click on done button.there is another view that have textFiled to display the contacts that user select. I need if the user start to remove name from textFiled by backspace,[image]

to be removed the all name and remove also the id from array that will send the id's to server.
my code is

```
let idArray = ["1","2","3","4"]
let valueArray = ["Ahmad","ali","jean","sara"]
let StringVar = ""

//*Here I send the array to string to append "," to be showed in textFiled*
for item in valueArray {
            print("Found \(item)")
            StringVar = StringVar + item + ","
        }

textFiled?.text = StringVar
```

any help please ??

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be a string parsing headache for this type of work. 
Maybe you might consider using instead:
A horizontal UICollectionView for your person list. This collectionView's cell include a borderles UITextView (or if it readonly then it can be UILabel) and small UIButton with close(x) icon for delete action for every single person.

Designer looks like this:
[image]

this view will work in a way that is compatible with your array.

Here are the things you should pay attention to:

1- Bind collectionView with your array as if it was UITableView

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.personList.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = personCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "personNameCell", for: indexPath) as! personNameCell
...
}
```

2- Don't forget reload collectionView after deletion

```
func personDeleteButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    //remove item from your list
    ...
    ...
    personCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

3- Set dimensions of cells dynamically

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
...
```

Comment: I can't do this solution, because next step I'll let the user type the name in the text Filed and from my code I'll search in the contact list to display it in text filed

Comment: Ok, of course your choice is yours.
But inside cells there is an editable textField. So you can get all these string with loop on collectionView or just specific one. And then you can merge, split, add new, delete. As a result you can get the string you want in this collectionView and do what you want, search or let another textField.

Answer (score 1):

I did not implement such a thing before. but, I think I would have tried `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)` from `UITextFieldDelegate`. 
when a user will try to delete a character, you can remove the entire string between the two commas or from the first/last comma to the start/end of the string